# Flutter does not update subwidget

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a widget, which contains a subwidget. It get the last and new value in the build method like this:

```
children: <Widget>[
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1.0,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: CircleWidget(_lastWindSpeed/10, _speed/10),
                      ))
                  ],
                ),
```

The state will be updatet with

```
setState
```

But the widget does not get updated if there are new values.

Did anyone see the issue there?

The class is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'circle_painter.dart';

class CircleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double _start;
  final double _finish;
  CircleWidget(this._start, this._finish);

  @override
  State<CircleWidget> createState() => new _CircleState();
}

class _CircleState extends State<CircleWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  Animation<double> animation;
  double _fraction;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var controller = AnimationController(duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: widget._start, end: widget._finish).animate(controller)
      ..addListener((){
        setState(() {
          _fraction = animation.value;
        });
      });
    controller.forward();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CustomPaint(
        painter: new CirclePainter(_fraction));
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

If you want your animation to restart when the values of the `CircleWidget` change, you need to use the [`didUpdateWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/didUpdateWidget.html) lifecycle.  `initState` is called only once, while `didUpdateWidget` is called every time your the corresponding widget is recreated - note that the values might be the same if a parent widget rebuilt too.

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(CircleWidget oldWidget) {
  if (oldWidget._start != widget._start || 
    oldWidget._end != widget._end) {
    // values changed, restart animation.
    controller
      ..reset()
      ..forward();
  }
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
}
```

Comment: "didn't get it work" isn't really descriptive enough to help you.  An additional point is that a 10 ms animation is less than one frame, so they will always complete instantly

Comment: I think I am gonna use streams for this example, i will try it another way later, thanks so far :-)

Answer (score 6):

I want to post an alternative solution to the given solution above.
if you want `StatefulWidget` to update its underlying data when you call `setState` or inside a `StreamBuilder` you should pass a `UniqueKey` to the `StatefulWidget` constructor.
The behavior of fullter when `setState` is called is to check if the type did not change in case of `StatefulWidget` if not nothing will be updated.
If you add a `UniqueKey` to the constuctor, the flutter UI updater will check the key instead.
I hope this helps.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'circle_painter.dart';

class CircleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final double _start;
  final double _finish;
  CircleWidget(this._start, this._finish, Key:key):super(key:key); // <-- check this

  @override
  State<CircleWidget> createState() => new _CircleState();
}

class _CircleState extends State<CircleWidget> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

  Animation<double> animation;
  double _fraction;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var controller = AnimationController(duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 10), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: widget._start, end: widget._finish).animate(controller)
      ..addListener((){
        setState(() {
          _fraction = animation.value;
        });
      });
    controller.forward();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CustomPaint(
        painter: new CirclePainter(_fraction));
  }
}



children: <Widget>[
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 1.0,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: CircleWidget(_lastWindSpeed/10, _speed/10, key: UniqueKey()), // <---- add UniqueKey as key param here to tell futter to check keys instead of types
                      ))
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Using `UniqueKey` seems like a lot less hassle but someone told me it's not recommended. Why is that?

Comment: Because the widget using the UniqueKey is discarded on every rebuild.